# Why is Mathematica giving this answer for the derivative of 2^x?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to use Mathematica to take the derivative of 2^x with respect to x. It's giving me the attached answer, which is not correct. Am I doing something wrong? Why is it giving this answer?

[image]

Edit: The answer I'd expect it to give is ln(2) 2^x, as indicated by [this](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-derivative-of-2-x) explanation, which makes sense to me. Is the explanation incorrect?

Comment: What answer did you expect? Why would you think this is wrong?

Comment: [`Log`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) is $\ln$. There's also [`Log2`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log2.html?q=Log2) and [`Log10`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log10.html?q=Log10). Read the docs.

Comment: Ahh, got it! Thank you very much. Would you consider making this a full answer so that I could check it off?

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
 Exp[x Log[2]] == 2^x
```

> True